# How to expand particular parent in Jquery

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I have a menu made using jquery.I want that when i click on particular parent only child under that parent shud expand all other child under other parent shud get hide.
I have got parent id so based on that i can expand a particular parent.

My code is as follows.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var msg1;
  var msg14;
var msg = false;
alert((document.getElementById(''P17_LOCATION_ID'')).value);
alert(msg14);
$(''.dropdown_menu'').click(function(event) {
msg = !msg;
if (msg)'
$(this).parent(''.parent_menu'').find(''.child_menu'').slideDown("slow");
  else 
$(''.child_menu'').hide();
return false;
 });
' });
</script>
```

Here - `$(this).parent(''.parent_menu'').find(''.child_menu'').slideDown("slow");` is responsible for sliding down of child menu for parents but currently all the child menus are expanding which i want to stop and when i click on some parent then child under that parent only shud be displayed so how i can pass the id to this statement above.
Kindly suggest some solution

Answer (score 2):

$(expr).parent(sel) returns all parents of expr that match sel.  you wan't $(this).closest('.parent_menu')

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply.
I got what u meant but what i want is when user select any child items my page gets refreshed and hence all the submenu gets expanded so i want that after $(document).ready(function(){
I will be need to add something which will only expand a particular submenu whose parentid is passed which is accessible here.
Kindly suggest some solution as it is very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also use only the first element in the collection returned by `parent()`:

```
$(this).parent('.parent_menu').eq(0).find('.child_menu').slideDown('slow');
```

However, I agree that `closest()` is more elegant, and it basically does the same thing. Hope my post clarifies things for you, anyway.

Comment: hi
htp.p;
htp.p('<script>');
htp.p('  $(document).ready(function(){');
htp.p('  var msg14 = ($(''#P17_LOCATION_ID'').val());');
htp.p('  alert(msg14);');
htp.p('  $(''dd:not(:first)'').hide();');
htp.p('  $(''dt a'').click(function(){');
htp.p('  $(''dd:visible'').slideUp("slow");');
htp.p('  $(this).parent().next().slideDown("slow");');
htp.p('  return false;');
htp.p(' });');
htp.p(' });');
htp.p('</script>');
here i am able to see the first parent on page refresh say i want toview the last parent id expanded when page refreshes so is there any metho instead of :first which i can use here